# process substitution in bash, sometimes I have to press "Enter"

Tags: linux, bash

I'm just learning to use process substitution in bash. Here's the command:

```
echo TEXT > >(tee log)
```

This is a pointless command but the thing is I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after I run it. Why is that?

Sometimes this happens with more useful commands like:

```
ls SOME_NON_EXISTING_FILE 2> >(tee log)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not really needed, you can just enter next command e.g. `date` and check. What is happening that because of process substitution your command exits first and then output gets written on your terminal, that is the reason you get false impression of need to press an <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: But why doesn't bash detect that it should print a prompt?

Comment: Actually BASH does print the prompt. But as I wrote it is because output from substituted command gets painted on tty after BASH has already written the next line's `PS1`.